# How to debug CUDA kernels in Visual studio or Parallel Nsight

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, cuda, gpu, nsight

I have CUDA 4.1 SDK with Parallel Nsight 2.1 installed on Win7 x64. I want to debug my CUDA kernels, how to do this? Is this possible with one GPU? There is a utility Nsight Monitor. I have tried it, first disabled Timeout Detection and Recovery on Windows, and disable WPF, as Nsight monitor told me. I set a breakpoint in VS, run the code but nothing happend. Nsight monitor said i am connected. So can i debug in VS or shall i debug in Parallel Nsight? How to? Thanks a million.

Comment: How did you run the code from VS? Using "Start CUDA debugging"? Was everything synchronized properly? Is the breakpoint in device or host code?

Comment: Breakpoint is in the device code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only have one GPU then you cannot do debugging with Parallel Nsight 2.1 since stopping the GPU stops the display (Nsight stops you doing this). With Parallel Nsight 2.2 (release candidate [now available](http://developer.nvidia.com/content/nvidia-parallel-nsight-22-rc1-now-available-0)) you can now do local debugging with a single GPU.

So you're on the right track (disabling TDR/WPF etc.) but you'll need to update to Parallel Nsight 2.2 to debug with a single GPU.

Comment: As Bart pointed out in the comments, if you want to be able to debug device code you need to start the program using the "Start CUDA debugging" menu option (in the Nsight menu, can't check the exact name right now). If you just start using the normal Visual Studio route (Start with debugging or whatever, i.e. F5) then you are debugging host code and hence device breakpoints will not be hit. At the moment you can't debug both at the same time unless you start a separate Visual Studio instance and use it to attach to the host executable.