# Support for local single GPU debugging

Tags: cuda

Which combinations of GPU hardware, operating systems and NVIDIA software / drivers support local, single GPU debugging?

Comment: duplicate :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153668/how-to-debug-cuda-kernels-in-visual-studio-or-parallel-nsight Or isn't it ?

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. I was interested in finding out if the CUDA 5 production release for Linux includes this feature, but I thought a more generic answer would be nice.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate. The linked question gives one possible answer, not the range of possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single-GPU debugging works:

1. On Windows using Nsight Visual Studio edition.
2. On Mac or Linux when running in console mode (e.g. without windowing environments)

Also note that both GPUs do not need to be CUDA GPUs - e.g. we have tested several Linux setups that have Intel and NVIDIA GPUs with Intel driving the OS UI.

Comment: Thank you. Is the feature on the roadmap for the Nsight Eclipse Edition?

Comment: We understand how important this issue is and we are constantly investigating different approaches for enabling this in cuda-gdb.