# Debug cuda kernel on mexfunction by attaching Matlab with Nsight GPU Debugger

Tags: visual-studio-2010, matlab, debugging, cuda, nsight

I would like to ask how can we debug cuda kernel that is called from a mexfunction with VS 2010 and Nsight. I followed the instructions in http://http.developer.nvidia.com/NsightVisualStudio/2.2/Documentation/UserGuide/HTML/Content/Attach_CUDA_to_Process.htm but the attach button is not enabled in order to attach matlab.

PS: Win 7 64x, Matlab 2011 x64, VS 2010, CUDA SDK 5.5 64x, Nsight 3.1 64x, GForce 9600.

[image]

Comment: Note that there is no CUDA Type specified in the Type column aside to the Matlab row. This means that no CUDA usage is recognized in that process. Anyway, I have tried the guidelines in the webpage you have quoted and I have the same problem. My configuration is Win 7 64x, Matlab 2010a x64, VS 2010, CUDA 5.0 64x, Nsight 3.1 64x. What is not clear to me from the quoted procedure is how Nsight should recognize CUDA usage before invking the mex function. Therefore, I set a breakpoint before the kernel invoction and tried to attach from the same/new Visual Studio IDE, but nothing changed.

Comment: For your reference, this post [debugging cuda files in visual studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14386982/debugging-cuda-files-in-visual-studio) has the same unsolved problem.

Comment: Take a look at this http://http.developer.nvidia.com/NsightVisualStudio/3.0/Documentation/UserGuide/HTML/Content/Attach_CUDA_to_Process.htm it did not help me but it is the closer info I found relevant to our problem.

Comment: A very tiny piece of information. I have tried with setting the environmental variable `NSIGHT_CUDA_DEBUGGER = 1` systemwide, and now some processes expose the CUDA Type, but not Matlab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open Nsight Monitor *Nsight Visual Studio Edition 3.1 -> Nsight Monitor*
2. Go the Nsight Monitor Options (on the left of taskbar) -> CUDA -> Use this Monitor for CUDA attach ->true
3. Add environmental variable `NSIGHT_CUDA_DEBUGGER = 1` via *Advance System Settings -> Environmental Variables* and add the aforementioned variable both in *User* and *System* variables in the two panels.
4. Start Matlab and Visual Studio and try to attach Matlab with the Nsight debugger and qualifier the *Computer name*  and that it is.

Tested on Matlab 2011a 64x and VS 2010 with SP1.

[image]

Comment: It seems it is not necessary to set `NSIGHT_CUDA_DEBUGGER=1` as a _user_ environmental variable. Setting it as a _system_ environmental variable has been enough for me.

Comment: @JackOLantern It turns out you don't even need to set it except *inside MATLAB*, and this may even prevent system-wide performance degradation.  See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28638430/2778484) for details.

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to set the `NSIGHT_CUDA_DEBUGGER` environment variable **just for MATLAB**, so you don't have to slow down your entire system by having every process attachable. Quoting NVIDIA's Nsight documentation:

> Setting `NSIGHT_CUDA_DEBUGGER=1` can degrade the performance of an application, since the debugger is made resident. The effect is minimal on Tesla™ devices and headless devices; it is most severe on display devices with a desktop, where the debugger by necessity may need to serialize launches that would otherwise have been asynchronous. Therefore, **it’s not always desirable to set `NSIGHT_CUDA_DEBUGGER=1` at a system-wide or user-wide level**.

To set it in a running MATLAB session (and spare the rest of your system):

```
>> setenv('NSIGHT_CUDA_DEBUGGER','1')
```

Hit Refresh or reselect the Nsight GPU Debugger and it works:

[image]

You still need to configure Nsight to allow attaching, but it's a one-time setting:

[image]